Swift OpenAPI Generator Error (_OpenAPIGeneratorCore error)
I followed the exact steps from WWDC23's OpenAPI generator tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=US5Blei-5Kg&t=737s, however when I build the app, I got the following error
#if !(os(macOS) || os(Linux) || (os(iOS) && targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)))
#error(
    "_OpenAPIGeneratorCore is only to be used by swift-openapi-generator itself—your target should not link this library or the command line tool directly."
)
#endif

#if SWIFT_OPENAPI_STRICT_CONCURRENCY
#warning("Compiling with Strict Concurrency")
#endif

I read https://shape.dk/news-and-knowledge/leveraging-apples-new-swift-openapi-generator, in which the author said there's no way around the error, but I find it hard to believe that Apple will release a tutorial with no way of fixing this error.

I figured it out. So when adding the packages

swift-openapi-generator
swift-openapi-urlsession
swift-openapi-runtime

you have to deselect the target (set the target to none) for swift-openapi-generator! But select the target for the project for the rest of the two packages.

it solved the problem, but do you know the concepts behind this fix?
